# Not sure if this is a correct implementation of a test in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a homework assignment which tasks one to begin to write simple tests.

They use this as an example.

> Write an assertEqual function from scratch.
>
> It should compare actual and expected values with strict equality (not
>   typecasting).

**SUCCESS CASE**

```
function multiplyByTwo(n) {
  return n * 2; 
} 
var output = multiplyByTwo(2); 
// returns 4 assertEqual(output, 4, 'it doubles 2 to 4'); 
// console output: // passed
```

**FAILURE CASE**

```
function multiplyByTwo(n) {
  return (n * 2) + 1; // an incorrect implementation
}
var output = multiplyByTwo(2); // returns 5
assertEqual(output, 4, 'it doubles 2 to 4');
// console output:
// FAILED [it doubles 2 to 4] Expected "4", but got "5"
```

This is what I have so far...

```
function compareWithStrictEquality(val1, val2) {
  return val1 === val2;
}

function assertEqual(actual, expected, testName) {
  testName = assertEqual.name + ' : should compare actual and expected values with strict equality (not typecasting).';
  console.log(testName);

 return (actual()) === typeof 'boolean';

}
```

I didn't go to far because I don't know where to begin! Also—I have worked with some JavaScript [assesments](https://github.com/rmurphey/js-assessment) in the past. Looking at the example made me think I had to write some kind of complex logic analogous to the test suite I linked to...How else would it figure out if your function was doing?

Somehow I believe it is far simpler and I am overthinking it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have to do deep object inspection (more on that later), it looks like you're on the right path and nearly done actually.

In your `assertEqual` you have to do the comparison and return the message. A simple way to do this:

```
var passed = compareWithStrictEquality(actual, expected)
if (passed) console.log('passed')
else console.log('FAILED ' + testName + ' Expected ' + expected + ', but got ' + actual)
```

Note this is not going to work if you need to compare objects. For example:

```
{} === {}
// output: false
```

If you need to do `object` comparison you'll need some form of deep comparison: [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)